# how to call async web service in c#?

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous

Below is the way i am currently calling the web service to project,

```
  public JsonResult CruiseBE_Data1(string cruise)
    {
        CruiseService GetPorts = new CruiseService();
        projectCruise.CruiseServiceASD.ServiceAuthHeader serviceAuthHeaderValue_Cruise = new projectCruise.CruiseServiceASD.ServiceAuthHeader();
        serviceAuthHeaderValue_Cruise.username = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        serviceAuthHeaderValue_Cruise.password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        GetPorts.ServiceAuthHeaderValue = serviceAuthHeaderValue_Cruise;

        string CruisePorts = "";

        CruisePorts = GetPorts.GetPorts();


        return Json(CruisePorts);
    }
```

What I am trying to do is i want to change above to async way of requesting can any one please guide me how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to wrap your `GetPorts.GetPorts()` call in a `Task.Run()`:

```
CruisePorts = await Task.Run(() => GetPorts.GetPorts());
```

But take care, that your method then must be defined as

```
public async Task<JsonResult> CruiseBE_Data1(string cruise)
```